# How to install REQUESTS, SELENIUM and SCRAPY in google colaboratory?

Tags: python, selenium, pip, scrapy, google-colaboratory

people,

How can I install those libraries in google colab, I type the next:

```
!pip install requests
!pip install beautifulsoup4
!pip install lxml
!pip install selenium
!pip install pillow
!pip install pymongo
!pip install scrapy
```

but receive the next error:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
requests 2.23.0 requires urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1, but you have urllib3 1.26.8 which is incompatible.
datascience 0.10.6 requires folium==0.2.1, but you have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
```

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
selenium 4.1.3 requires urllib3[secure,socks]~=1.26, but you have urllib3 1.25.11 which is incompatible.
datascience 0.10.6 requires folium==0.2.1, but you have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: In one error, it says you have version 1.26.8 of `urllib3`, but the next error says you have version 1.25.11 of `urllib3`. That should not be possible in the same environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can install those libraries in google colab with %:

%pip install scrapy

Comment: How does this address the question? Using `!pip` works just fine in Colab.